# Getting clear with special conditional statement

Tags: javascript

I will show you a little part of my app where I am wondering which is the proper way to put a conditional I am working on. If both ways I will show you are correct, I would like you to tell me the consequences/adversities

```
if ((some.thing === '' || 0) || (some.how === '' || 0)) {
      //something is going on here
}
```

that is how I have it so far, is there something bad with it?

or should be better this way:

```
if ((some.thing === '' || some.thing === 0) || (some.how === '' || some.how === 0)) {
       //something is going on here
}
```

so what are your suggestions ? is it the same result at the end?

**EDIT**

Adding another way:

```
if (some.thing === '' || some.thing === 0 || some.how === '' || some.how === 0) {
       //something is going on here
}
```

Comment: those 2 are not equivalent.

Comment: @DanielA.White that's what I need to know, why ?

Comment: In either case, always go clarity over brevity. Even if the 1st worked, the second is better because I can read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `||` operator has precedence over the comparison operators.

So `some.thing === '' || 0` is the same as `(some.thing === '') || (0)`. It:

- will evaluate to `0` if `some.thing === ''` is `false` or
- will evaluate to `true` if `some.thing === ''` is `true`.

Look at this example (as running in a JavaScript console):

```
> some = { thing: 0 }
  Object { thing: 0 }
> some.thing === ''
  false
> some.thing === '' || 0  // this is like false || 0
  0
> some = { thing: '' }
  Object { thing: "" }
> some.thing === ''
  true
> some.thing === '' || 0  // this is like true || 0
  true
```

Prefer something like the last expression you wrote.

**EDIT:** Actually both `''` and `0` are [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in JavaScript, so you can just simply write your complete expression as:

```
if (!some.thing || !some.how) {
  //something is going on here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This part looks fishy to me:

```
some.thing === '' || 0
```

Do you mean this instead:

```
some.thing === '' || some.thing === 0
```

`0` is always falsy, so the expression `some.thing === '' || 0` is always equivalent to `some.thing === ''`

**EDIT**

You need the final expression:

```
(some.thing === '' || some.thing === 0 || some.how === '' || some.how === 0)
```

Comment: Actually, `some.thing === '' || 0` will be `true` if `some.thing === ''`, and it will be `0` otherwise.  See http://jsfiddle.net/8vemov1k/

Comment: great hint for me, what do you think about the 3rd way I just add ? look at the question

Answer (score 0):

`||` is not like SQL's `IN` clause. Basically this is what you are doing:

```
someBoolean || 0
```

so it never compares `some.thing` with type-safe equality with the `Number` `0`.

Answer (score 0):

On your first example, you are basically doing this:

```
if ((condition1 || condition2) || (condition3 || condition4))
```

Now condition1 and condition 3 can be true or false, depending on what's the content of some.thing and some.how, but conditions 2 and 4 will always be false (0 is false), so basically what you are saying is:

```
if (condition1 || condition3)
```

Your second example:

```
if (condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4)
```

Your third example, looks more like this:

```
if ((condition1 || condition2) || (condition3 || condition4))
```

And now all of them can be false or true (for both second and third examples).

Keep in mind, though, if for example some.thing is '' while some.how is 'something' the whole set of conditions will be true.

Answer (score 0):

Use the second code snippet. The first code snippet isn't valid, because

```
if ((some.thing === '' || 0) || (some.how === '' || 0)) {
      //something is going on here
}
```

fist evaluate `some.thing === ''` which can be true of false then it return this result OR false, so your code is finally

```
if (some.thing === '' || some.how === '') {
      //something is going on here
}
```